# podman not running container in quay setup in centos9

Tags: devops, centos8, podman, quay.io, podman-compose

I am setting up quay in a vm with centos distro. This is the guide I am following: [quay deploy guide](https://docs.projectquay.io/deploy_quay.html)

once I install Podman I am trying to run first container with below command:

I set up this env variable:

```
export QUAY=QUAY
```

and made a dir of same name in home:

```
mkdir QUAY
```

once I install Podman I am trying to run first container with below command:

```
$ sudo podman run -d --rm --name postgresql-quay \
  -e POSTGRESQL_USER=quayuser \
  -e POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=quaypass \
  -e POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=quay \
  -e POSTGRESQL_ADMIN_PASSWORD=adminpass \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  -v $QUAY/postgres-quay:/var/lib/pgsql/data:Z \
  registry.redhat.io/rhel8/postgresql-10:1
```

and I am getting following error:

```
sudo podman run -d --rm --name postgresql-quay   -e POSTGRESQL_USER=quayuser   -e POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=quaypass   -e POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=quay   -e POSTGRESQL_ADMIN_PASSWORD=adminpass   -p 5432:5432   -v QUAY/postgres-quay:/var/lib/pgsql/data:Z   registry.redhat.io/rhel8/postgresql-10:1
Error: error creating named volume "QUAY/postgres-quay": error running volume create option: names must match [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*: invalid argument
```

Comment: @ErikSjölund thanks this did it. if you post as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bind mount needs to be specified as an absolute path or a relative path that starts with `./` or `../`.

In other words instead of

`-v QUAY/postgres-quay:/var/lib/pgsql/data:Z`

use

`-v ./QUAY/postgres-quay:/var/lib/pgsql/data:Z`

(I replaced `$QUAY` with its value `QUAY`)